# Loop through an array to generate a new array. It returns 0 at the end of the loop

Tags: node.js, loops, foreach

There are 4900 books in the database. I expect to have the same number of books in the new array at the end of the loop. However, I am getting a zero length for the booksArray. What could be the problem and possible solution?

```
const getOverview = async(req, res) => {

    const books = await Book.find();

    const booksArray = new Array();

    books.forEach(book => {

        const url =`https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/${book.isbn}key=${process.env.KEY}`;

        request.get(url).then(result => {

            parseString(result, (error, goodReadsResult) => {

                const goodreadsBook = goodReadsResult.GoodreadsResponse.book[0];

                booksArray.push(goodreadsBook);

            })
        });
    })
    console.log(booksArray.length);
};
```

Comment: `request()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  That means the callbacks happen long AFTER your loop is done.  So, you are attempting to use the array before it has been populated.

Comment: How can I make synchronous requests to goodreads API without request()?

Comment: What does `parseString()` do?  Can you include the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

First a bit of an overview.  Node.js does all networking as non-blocking and asynchronous.  That means when you make a networking request, it starts the operation and immediately returns and continues executing the rest of your code.  A callback or promise associated with that asynchronous operation gets called sometime later.

In your specific case, your entire `.forEach()` loop runs to completion starting all the networking requests in it before any of them have finished.  Thus you are doing `console.log(booksArray.length);` before any of your callbacks have run and thus the array is still empty.

Any time you want to sequence or coordinate more than one asynchronous operation in node.js you will want to use promises.  It's been built into the language for a couple years now and it's just a massively better way to program with asynchronous operations.  I would suggest you find some good tutorials on how promises work and learn them.

Then, the library you are using `request()` is old and has been put in maintenance mode and does not support promises.  There are a variety of more [modern alternatives](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  I personally use the [`got()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) and that's what I've illustrated below.

Then, I don't know what your `parseString()` function is, but it apparently doesn't use promises and appears to be asynchronous so, in order to use it in a promise-based workflow, I "promisified" it using `util.promisify()` which is built-into node.js.  If it has a promise interface, you should just use that directly.

So anyway, here's what I would suggest:

```
const got = require('got');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const ps = promisify(parseString);

// this function returns a promise  
async function getOverview(req, res) {

    const books = await Book.find();
    const booksArray = await Promise.all(books.map(book => {
        const url =`https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/${book.isbn}key=${process.env.KEY}`;
        let bookData = await got(url);
        return ps(bookData);
    }));

    console.log(booksArray.length);

    // make the booksArray be the resolved value of the promise returned
    // by this async function
    return booksArray;
}
```

This makes all your networking calls in parallel and then uses `Promise.all()` to indicate when they are all done and to collect all the results in order.

If, for some reason, you can't make all these requests in parallel (like there are so many that the target server objects), then you can run them one at a time too like this:

```
const got = require('got');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const ps = promisify(parseString);

// this function returns a promise
async function getOverview(req, res) {

    const books = await Book.find();
    const booksArray = [];
    for (let book of books) {
        const url =`https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/${book.isbn}key=${process.env.KEY}`;
        let bookData = await got(url);
        let data = await ps(bookData);
        booksArray.push(data);
    }

    console.log(booksArray.length);

    // make the booksArray be the resolved value of the promise returned
    // by this async function
    return booksArray;
}
```

And, since these are `async` functions, they return a promise so that caller must use `await` or `.then()` to get the value from the promise.

```
getOverview(...).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If you actually intend to pass `req` and `res` into that function and use them there, then you will probably need local error handling too so if any of your `await` operations reject, you can catch that error and send an error response.  You would do that with `try/catch` inside the function body.  You can probably just use one top level `try/catch` and then send an error response inside the `catch` handler.